# mySQL : How to fetch successive numbers

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table with an INT column `exp_num`. The numbers start with 1 are successive. But a bunch of records can have the same number. Some has 1, others 2, others 3 and so on. Now I want to fetch all those numbers to display them in a `dropdown` box to choose one of this numbers as a condition for a DB search. When I `select` the column `exp_num` and `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` I get on one hand for each entry an array and on the other hand I get all numbers like this

```
    [10] => array { [exp_num] =>[3] }   
    [11] => array { [exp_num] =>[3] }   
    [12] => array { [exp_num] =>[3] }   
    [13] => array { [exp_num] =>[4] }
    [14] => array { [exp_num] =>[4] }
    [15] => array { [exp_num] =>[4] }
    [16] => array { [exp_num] =>[4] }   
...
```

All I need finally is one array with values of successive numbers like

```
array {   
[1]   
[2]   
[3]   
[4]   
[5]   
}
```

and so on.

How to achieve that in one mySQL statement ?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT exp_num FROM Table

Answer (score 1):

Distinct keyword is what you're looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT exp_num FROM Table
```

Therefore you need to get result with `$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);`
or use `array_values()` with your fetch solution.